# Symbols not found for architecture x86_64 implied type conversion not working

Tags: c++, templates

Xcode 7.2.1 compiler.

Why will this not compile? I would expect that the second line would infer the type, but I'm getting the error posted. Thx.

```
int square(int);
template <typename T>
T square(T x) { return x * x; }

int main() {
    cout << square<int>(2) << endl; //Compiles, works
    cout << square(2) << endl; // Error below!?
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're telling the compiler that a function `int square(int);` exists, but you don't define it. Note that the template instantiation with `T = int` is *not* a definition for `int square(int)`.

Comment: A non-template is a better match for resolving overloads than a template.

Comment: I recommend against this template as it allows you to supply types that don't make sense, such as `s = square("Hello");`  and `string s, t; t = square(s);`.  You should probably overload the `square` function with valid types (there aren't many).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are declaring a function as well as a template function.

```
int square(int);
```

This says that there is some function, `square`, that exists elsewhere.

```
template <typename T>
T square(T x) { return x * x; }
```

Says there is a template called `square` for arbitrary types.  When you call it directly via `square<int>(2)` you are explicitly referencing the template.  When you try to infer it by `square(2)` the first, declared but undefined function `int square(int)` is selected, and you get an undefined reference error.

I believe you just want a templated function, so you should delete the `int square(int)` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to link in object file with definition of fuction(it is preferred by compiler over function template as exact match):

```
int square(int);
```

as this one selected on line:

```
cout << square(2) << endl; // Error below!?
```